# How to decrypt a message sent via Pidgin-Encryption?

Tags: linux, pidgin, google-talk, public-key-encryption

A friend sent me an offline Google Talk message that was encrypted via Pidgin-Encryption. It didn't appear in my Pidgin logs because I wasn't logged in when it was sent, but I do have the encrypted message in my Google Talk logs. I have her public key as well as my own private key stored in my .purple directory. How can I use these to decrypt the message?

Comment: As far as I know, pidgin doesn't support encryption, Maybe the message was encrypted using OTR ( off the record messaging ). I thought that OTR creates temporary session keys and exchanges them using the public/private key pair, if this really is the case, the easiest ( and probably only ) way to decrypt the message would be to ask your friend what she wrote! But as I said: I don"t know for sure if this is the case.

Comment: [Pidgin-Encryption exists](http://pidgin-encrypt.sourceforge.net/), and apparently uses RSA.

Comment: You may take a look at "openssl rsautl".

Comment: I did, but haven't been able to figure out how to make it recognize the keys.